# function to filter category from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries containing investment assets, categories, risk ratings, etc.

See the below example:

```
inv = [
    {
  "rating": "Low",
  "score": "1",
  "type": "Capital Preservation",
  "assets": [
      "Money Market Fund",
      "Treasury Bills",
      "Easy Will"
  ]
},
    {
  "rating": "Moderate",
  "score": "2",
  "type": "Income & Growth",
  "assets": [
      "Euro-bond Fund",
      "Fixed Income Fund",
      "Ethical Fund",
      "Easy Will"
  ]
},
     {
  "rating": "High",
  "score": "3",
  "type": "Growth",
  "assets": [
      "Discovery Fund",
      "Local Stocks",
      "Foreign Stocks",
      "Easy Will"
  ]
}
]
```

I am working on a function that would have another list of dictionaries passed as a parameter.
The function is meant to evaluate the different assets(with investment amounts) of the user and return the investment category with the highest amount.

See an example of the user's data that would be passed as the function parameter

```
user1 = [
    {
        "asset": "Discovery Fund",
        "amount": 600000
    },
       {
        "asset": "Money Market Fund",
        "amount": 200000
    },
       {
        "asset": "Ethical Fund",
        "amount": 1000000
    }
]
```

Right now, I have been able to write a function that accepts a string representing the particular asset and return the rating for that asset.

```
def getCategory(category):  
    f = 0
    for m in inv_class:
        assets = m['assets']
        for a in assets:
            if a == category:
                f = 1
                print(m["rating"])
    if f == 0:
        print(category + ' does not exist')
        return None

getCategory("Ethical Fund")
Output - moderate, high
```

I want to use the score to serve as weights for each category. So my function should calculate the score based on the input of the user's investments.

The calculation of the score (for the user data above) by hand goes like these:

```
Money Market Fund = Low rating
Ethical Fund = Moderate rating
Discovery Fund = High rating

* The average of the funds are
Money Market Fund = 200/1800 = 0.11111
Ethical Fund = 1000/1800 = 0.5556
Discovery Fund = 600/1800 = 0.333

* Multiply by their corresponding weights/scores
Money Market Fund = 0.11111 * 1 = 0.11111
Ethical Fund = 0.5556 * 2 = 1.1112 ---> This is the highest
Discovery Fund = 0.333 * 3 = 0.9999

* Add all the results
0.11111 + 1.11112 + 0.99999 = 2.22 ---> Which is approximately 2
So the score is 2, with a rating of "Moderate".
```

Is this calculation right for my use case and how can I turn this into code in the most efficient way?

What is the best way to approach this problem. I want my function to have a list of dictionaries containing the user assets and amounts and evaluates and calculates an average score and return the rating of the one with the closest score.

Please I appreciate any help or guidance.

Thanks

Comment: I think the first thing of approaching this problem is to work out the general business logic of how to arrive at a certain rating. Do you always just pick the rating of the asset the user has invested the most in? What if a user has invested to equal amounts? I would do that on paper, to work out the logic and make it work for a lot of cases. Then think about how that translates to code. Happy to chat more about it.

Comment: hi @ccarstens, I have edited my question with the business logic. I would be using the score as weights. Thanks

Comment: Are the values like `200/1800` calculated for every user or are they constant?
Key to solving this is to break down the problem in smaller subproblems. So think about what steps you would perform if you had a single user and a single asset. How would a function for that look like? When that works, extend it to support multiple assets. When that works, put it in a loop to work on multiple users. Focus on making functions really good at one thing. It's better to have multiple specialised functions than one hefty one.